# Configuring git auto completion in .bash_profile

Tags: git, autocomplete, bash, nano

I'm having trouble installing git auto completion into my bash profile. 
I've attached a version of the bash script. Does anyone know why my the auto completion in git isn't working when I save and exit nano? Thanks!
[image]

Comment: try saving as `.git-completion.sh` and compile `.bash_profile` after that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to logout and log back in to force .bash_profile to run.

or to try if it is working right away, run

source ~/.git-completion.bash

source ~/.bash_profile would also work